# How to make a UIButton always stay above the keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

How can I make a a `UIButton` which appears only when keyboard is popped up and it always stay above the keyboard, like an accessory to the keyboard, which is exclusive to that VC. I have a `view` in my VC which has 4 `UIButtons` and I want to add that view as an accessory view to my `textField` I'm writing this code.. but I'm getting a `SIGABRT`

```
@IBOutlet weak var colorSelector: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let customView = colorSelector
    textField.inputAccessoryView = customView

}
```

Comment: The problem of your code is that, when you add `customView` to the `inputAccessoryView`, this `customView` already has parent view. so it will crash.

Comment: A simple fix is that add `customView.removeFromSuperview()` before `textField.inputAccessoryView = customView`

Comment: @Elvin My app is working but I can not see the `colorSelector`